# C#. Получить свойство экземпляра класса в коллекции SortedList

Tags: c#, .net

Есть код:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person p = new Person{ Name = "Best", LastName="User"};
        Person p1 = new Person{ Name = "Best1", LastName="User1"};
        SortedList mySL = new SortedList();
        mySL.Add("2", p);
        mySL.Add("1", p1);

        for(int i =0; i < mySL.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:\t{1}", mySL.GetKey(i), mySL.GetByIndex(i));
        }         
    }
}
    
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

который вернёт:

```
1:      ConsoleApp.Person
2:      ConsoleApp.Person
```

Есть ли возможность в отсортированном листе получить свойство `Name`?

Comment: Да, это можно сделать. C# есть синтаксис позволяющий обратиться к свойству объекта. Выглядит следующим образом: `person.Name`, работает со всеми публичными свойствами объектов. При этом не важно, откуда появляется `person`, это может быть, например, метод, как в вашем случае `mySL.GetByIndex(i)` вернёт (вероятно) объект класса `Person`, а значит к нему можно обратиться по способу который я описал выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по синтаксису, вы используете класс `SortedList` из пространства имён `System.Collections`. То есть где-то выше у вас написано:

```
using System.Collections;
```

Этот класс работает с типами `object` и в качестве ключа, и в качестве значения.
Соответственно, при получении значения его нужно привести (скастить) к нужному типу, после чего можно обращаться к его свойствам:

```
var person = (Person)mySL.GetByIndex(i);
Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:\t{1} {2}", mySL.GetKey(i), person.Name, person.LastName);
```

---

Однако, типы в этом пространстве имён являются устаревшими.
Лучше использовать обобщённые коллекции.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

В современных проектах .NET 6 это пространство имён открыто по умолчанию, можно не добавлять эту строку вручную.

```
SortedList<string, Person> sortedList = new();
sortedList.Add("2", p);
sortedList.Add("1", p1);

for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Count; i++)
{
    var person = sortedList.Values[i];
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:\t{1} {2}", sortedList.Keys[i], person.Name, person.LastName);
}
```

Comment: Исчерпывающе. Спасибо.